# Getting regex value from ansible stdout

Tags: regex, ansible

I want to extract an boolean value from ansible command stdout:

```
 - name: Get Status
  ansible.builtin.command:
    cmd: "vault status"
  register: vault_status
  ignore_errors: true

- ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    vault_sealed: "{{ (vault_status.stdout | regex_search(regexp,'\\1')) == 'true' }} "
  vars:
    regexp: "Sealed\\s+(.+)\\n"
```

It brings that output

```
TASK [Get Status] **************************************************************
task path: /ansible/tasks/vault_setup.yml:124
fatal: [vault_instance]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["vault", "status"], "delta": "0:00:00.071161", "end": "2022-11-11 21:32:06.405020", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 2, "start": "2022-11-11 21:32:06.333859", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "Key                Value\n---                -----\nSeal Type          shamir\nInitialized        true\nSealed             true\nTotal Shares       6\nThreshold          3\nUnseal Progress    1/3\nUnseal Nonce       2e079ec7-772f-7811-801e-c098c68c0400\nVersion            1.12.1\nBuild Date         2022-10-27T12:32:05Z\nStorage Type       file\nHA Enabled         false", "stdout_lines": ["Key                Value", "---                -----", "Seal Type          shamir", "Initialized        true", "Sealed             true", "Total Shares       6", "Threshold          3", "Unseal Progress    1/3", "Unseal Nonce       2e079ec7-772f-7811-801e-c098c68c0400", "Version            1.12.1", "Build Date         2022-10-27T12:32:05Z", "Storage Type       file", "HA Enabled         false"]}
...ignoring

TASK [ansible.builtin.set_fact] ************************************************
task path: /ansible/tasks/vault_setup.yml:130
ok: [vault_instance] => {"ansible_facts": {"vault_sealed": "False "}, "changed": false}
```

Can anybody tell me, how to get the vault_sealed to the right value "true" ?

Thanks guys !

Comment: I think you'll find the "line oriented" view easier to work with: `{{ (vault_status.stdout_lines | select("match", "^Sealed") | map("split") | first)[1] }}`, assuming don't get more benefit from [`vault status -json`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/docs/commands/status#format). One will also observe the `vault_status.rc` is documented as "2" meaning it is sealed

Comment: Hi, wasn´t aware, that rc 2 means sealed :-( .... should have read the documentation :-) .... many thanks for this hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want to check if there is a match for a string, with the [`regex_search` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#searching-strings-with-regular-expressions), you don't need any parameter other than the regex.

To determine the end of line, rather use the option `multiline=True` and end your regex with a `$`, if you want to search from the beginning of the line, start with a `^`.

A successful or unsuccessful matching can be determined with `is not none` or `is none`.
In your case, to determine the successful matching of the regex, you have to use `is not none`.

Your task should work like this:

```yaml
- ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    vault_sealed: "{{ vault_status.stdout | regex_search(regexp, multiline=True) is not none }}"
  vars:
    regexp: "^Sealed\\s+.+$"
```

If you just want to detect the beginning of the line with the word `Sealed` followed by a space, you can also write your regex like this: `"^Sealed\\s"`

If you want to determine whether the word *true* follows *Sealed*, then you can choose the regex as: `"^Sealed\\s+true$"`
Your task like this:

```yaml
- ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    vault_sealed: "{{ vault_status.stdout | regex_search(regexp, multiline=True) is not none }}"
  vars:
    regexp: "^Sealed\\s+true$"
```

*Note: You have to make sure that you don't have a space after your jinja expression (`}} "`), so it should look like this: `}}"`. Otherwise the result will be interpreted as a string instead of a truth value.*

---

Example Task for string starting with `Sealed` :

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ vault_status.stdout | regex_search(regexp, multiline=True) is not none }}"
  vars:
    regexp: "^Sealed\\s+.+$"
    vault_status:
      stdout: "Sealed some thing."
```

Result:

```
TASK [debug] ***************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": true
}
```

---

Example Tasks for string `Sealed true`:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ vault_status.stdout | regex_search(regexp, multiline=True) is not none }}"
  vars:
    regexp: "^Sealed\\s+true$"
    vault_status:
      stdout: "{{ item }}"
  with_items:
    - "Sealed   true"
    - "Sealed true"
    - "Sealed false"
    - "Some error!"
```

Result:

```
TASK [debug] ***********************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=Sealed   true) => {
    "msg": true
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=Sealed true) => {
    "msg": true
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=Sealed false) => {
    "msg": false
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=Some error!) => {
    "msg": false
}
```

Comment: Huge answer my friend.....it is guys like you, who make stakeoverflow that powerful and important...... I have no more questions here :-)